# Множественное наследование объектов Javascript

Tags: ооп, javascript

Привет. Хочу сделать наследование от многих объектов. Есть прекрасная функция, которая решает проблемы с ИЕ

```
function inherit(proto) {
  function F() {}
  F.prototype = proto;
  var object = new F;
  return object;
}

var animal = { eats: true };

var rabbit = inherit(animal);

alert(rabbit.eats); // true
```

Теперь пытаюсь сделать возможность одним махом наследовать от множества объектов

```
function multi_inherit(){

    //Проверка переданных аргументов,проверка пройдет если был объект передан

    var toClass = {}.toString;
    var arr = [];//массив переданных объектов
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        if(toClass.call(arguments[i]).slice(8,-1).toLowerCase()=='object'){
            arr.push(arguments[i]);
        }   
    }

    //inherit:
    function F(){}  
    for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
        F.prototype['name' + j]=arr[j];
    }

    return new F();
}

var name={name: 'alex'} 
var surname={family: 'botvinick'}
var age={age: 18}

var roof=multi_inherit(name, surname, age);

console.log(roof);
```

Что Вы думаете по этому коду? Пример говнокода?
У меня проблема как сделать доступ к свойству напрямую без `name`, чтобы

```
roof.name0.name  был доступен просто `roof.name`
```

Comment: > Что Вы думаете по этому коду?Пример говнокода?

да :)

Comment: В чем именно?

Comment: Во первых просто плохо написан код, во вторых в вашем случае вообще не нужно наследование, нужно копирование + мне абсолютно не понятно на кой вам прототипы, ну и у вас не глубокое копирование, делаеться оно примерно так:


    function cloneTo(src) {
      for(var i=1; i<arguments.length; ++i) {
        var arg = arguments[i];
        for(var prop in arg) if (arg.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          src[prop] = arg[prop];
        }
      }
    }
    var o = {a:1,b:2};
    var o1 = {aa:1,bb:1,cc:1};
    var o2 = {ololo:true};
    cloneTo(o, o1, o2);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(o, null, '  '))

Comment: В общем вердикт - книжечка javascript good parts и лекции Крокфорда на ютубе.

Comment: Где я писал что мне нужно копипрование??Я хочу наследование!!!Так в чем заключается плохая манера написания кода?

Comment: @zloctb, эмм, ясно, удачи. Уважаемый, цели, как вы выразились, залошить, я не преследовал. Не пожалейте своего времени, изучите предложенные мною сабжи и вы сразу все поймете.

@zloctb, ок, чем, по вашему, отличаеться копирование от наследования?

Comment: Залошить это святое!!!Та я знаю чем копирование отличается от наследование и данные функции тоже применял на практике.

Comment: у вас не наследование объекта, а копирование свойств, например конструктор тут определить было бы весьма сложно.

Comment: @zloctb, хотеть вы можете все что угодно. В JavaScript попросту нет множественного наследования. А вот примеси есть.

Answer (score 7):

**В JavaScript нет множественного наследования.**

В отличии от большинства современных объектно ориентированных языков программирования, JavaScript наследование построено на базе прототипов, а не на базе классов. Каждый объект в JavaScript имеет внутреннее свойство `__proto__` которое содержит ссылку на другой объект, являющийся прототипом текущего. До принятия стандарта ES2015 не было надежного кросбраузерного способа получить или задать это свойство. Среда выполнения определяла это свойство автоматически, на основе значения свойства `prototype` функции конструктора. Приведу простой пример:

```
// Класс, определяющий животное.
var Animal = function() {};

// Подкласс, определяющий кролика.
var Rabbit = function() {};
Rabbit.prototype = new Animal();

// Создаем экземпляр кролика и проверяем, к каким "классам" он относится.
var bugsBunny = new Rabbit();

// Багз Банни является экземпляром "класса" Rabbit
console.log(bugsBunny instanceof Rabbit); // true
// Багз Банни является экземпляром "класса" Animal
console.log(bugsBunny instanceof Animal); // true
// Багз Банни является экземпляром "класса" Object. Это вполне логично,
// поскольку прототипом "класса" Animal является пустой объект.
console.log(bugsBunny instanceof Object);
// А вот и доказательство этого факта.
console.log(Animal.prototype); // "Object {}"

// "Класс" Ни один из экземпляров класса Array не входит в цепочку
// прототипов нашего кролика.
console.log(bugsBunny instanceof Array); // false
```

Пример выше очень уж упрощен и, на самом деле, *не является полноценной реализацией* классового (от слова "класс") наследования в JavaScript. В тоже время, из него становится очевидным, что у класса может быть один и только один предок, поскольку у функции конструктора есть **всего одно** свойство `prototype` (а у объекта всего одно свойство `__proto__`).

Вы, наверное, можете возразить, что в качестве значения свойства `prototype` вы можете использовать некую смесь свойств из нескольких объектов, но фактически эта "смесь" будет экземпляром класса `Object`. (Вы даже можете ухитриться вызвать каждый из конструкторов наследуемых "классов" в конструкторе вашего "наследника".) Если все сделано правильно, то все эти ухищрения будут работать, но в данном случае **нельзя говорить о множественном наследовании**. В этом легко убедиться, по результатам работы оператора `instanceof` используя родительские классы в качестве правого операнда.

**Что же делать?**

В JavaScript для подобных целей используются **примеси**. Идея заключается в том, что вы используете обычное (единичное) наследование, а остальную функциональность "подмешиваете" в полученный класс. В самом простом случае, это можно сделать с помощью вот такой функции:

```
var mixin = function(targetConstructor, mix) {
    for (var i in mix) {
        if (mix.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            targetConstructor.prototype[i] = mix[i];
        }
    }
};

var cookieEaterMix = {
    eatCookie: function() {
        console.log('Om-nom-mon');
    }
};

var Animal = function() {};
mixin(Animal, cookieEaterMix);

var cookieMoster = new Animal();
cookieMonster.eatCookie(); // Выведет "Om-nom-nom"
```