# Цепочка наследования

Tags: javascript, наследование, prototype, прототипное-наследование

Нужна помощь с реализацией такой вот задачи - функция должна принять массив функций и соединить их в цепочку наследования, после чего новый объект должен иметь доступ к методам переданных прототипов

```
const ExtendedSquare = chain(Square, Polygon, Shape);
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/215401/256824

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так можно нахимичить:

```js
function chain(...fs) {
  var ps = fs.map(f => f.prototype)
  
  fs.reverse()
  ps.unshift(Object.create(null))

  function Res(...args) {
    var me = Object.create(null)

    for (var f of fs) {
      Object.setPrototypeOf(me, f.prototype)
      me = f.apply(me, args) || me
    }
    
    Object.setPrototypeOf(me, new.target.prototype)
    
    return me
  }

  Res.prototype = new Proxy(ps[0], {
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, name) {
      var res

      for (var p of ps) {
        if (res = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(p, name) /* assignment */) {
          break
        }
      }
      
      return res
    },
    
    ownKeys(target) {
      return Array.from(new Set(ps.flatMap(p => [Object.getOwnPropertyNames(p), Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(p)])))
    },
    
    has(target, name) {
      for (var p of ps) {
        if (name in p) {
          return true
        }
      }
      
      return false
    },
    
    get(target, name, receiver) {
      for (var p of ps) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(p, name)) {
          return p[name]
        }
      }
      
      for (var p of ps) {
        if (name in p) {
          return p[name]
        }
      }
    },
  })

  return Res;
}

function X(x) { this.x = x }
X.prototype.getX = function () { return this.x }

function Y(x, y) { this.y = y }
Y.prototype.getY = function () { return this.y }

function Z(x, y, z) { this.z = z }
Z.prototype.getZ = function () { return this.z }

var Q = chain(Z, Y, X)
var obj = new Q(1, 2, 3)

console.log(obj.x, obj.y, obj.z)
console.log(obj.getX(), obj.getY(), obj.getZ())

console.log(obj + "")

Y.prototype.toString = function () { return this.x + " " + this.y }
console.log(obj + "")

X.prototype.toString = function () { return this.x }
console.log(obj + "")

Z.prototype.toString = function () { return this.x + " " + this.y + " " + this.z }
console.log(obj + "")
```